# Add always / just once to Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: java, android, android-intent, actionview

I'm trying to set an application default through an Intent, see code below:

```
{
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("Documents/pdf"), filepath);

        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Intent createChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Open In");

        PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        if(createChooser.resolveActivity(pm) != null )
        {
            context.startActivity(createChooser);
        }
}
```

I want to achieve the following :[Intent with Always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXg7Y.png)

But I get the following : 
[createChooser intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjJC0.jpg)

I have also tried to start the original intent and also get the same result, code below :

> context.startActivity(intent); // removed createChooser intent

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are unable to set defaults for app depending on the android os. This feature has been removed on newer android versions.

The way I got around it was, check if the user has the app installed, if not redirect them to the google play store for download.